# Odoo Webservices in PHP using XMLRPC

Tags: php, web-services, xml-rpc, odoo

I am using the Odoo web services in PHP via XMLRPC.

It is working well and showing up the data, however I want to decrease my workload using the (Odoo ACL) access rights to show and hide the data for different type of the users based on the role.

Is it possible to show the data based upon the user roles? If possible please give me the snippet of the code to do this. I just want to use the XMLRPC not the RIPCORD Library because whole my code is already worked and i use the XMLRPC for this.

Comment: I have edited your question to improve readability, etc. but you should edit it further to add more information. Please see "[*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" for some pointers.